# AutoComplete Textbox in Apache Trinidad

Tags: jsf-1.2, trinidad

I am using Apache Trinidad with JSF 1.2 in my application. I need to create an autocomplete textbox in my application. But I could not find an in-built autocompleter in the Trinidad tag library. Is there a way to do it using Trinidad tags?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this cannot be done out of the box just using Trinidad tags.

However, you could use a [`<tr:inputText>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_inputText.html) component, and write your own Javascript change listener to do some [Apache Trinidad Partial Page Rendering](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/ppr.html) to filter the contents of a [`<tr:selectOneListbox>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_selectOneListbox.html).